# Animation is not applied to ::-webkit-slider-thumb

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have created some custom styles for input[type="range"] elements. I have created the following animation

```
@-webkit-keyframes balla {
    from {transform:rotate(0);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

which I apply to:

```
input[type="range"].twirl::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    -webkit-animation:balla 5s infinite;
    background: url(sliders/1.png)no-repeat center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

My problem is that if I apply the same animation to any other element in the page it will work but not for my slider.
Here is my css:

```
<input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" id="slider" class="romvos no-shadow twirl">
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You want the animation on the input or in the slider thumb? If you apply same animation to input, then it works

Comment: i want it to the slider thumb

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this transformation will work only on chromium(not chrome).I tested it on firefox(windows and linux) and chrome(windows and linux) and only works on chromium

Answer (score 0):

That's (currently) not possible. Webkit does support animations on some pseudo-elements, but the special pseudo selector `::webkit-slider-thumb` is not one of them.

Look [here](http://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element-animation) for a simple way to detect animation support on a pseudo-element.

Comment: Chromium uses the [Blink](http://www.chromium.org/blink) rendering engine, not WebKit. I'm not sure, but it may explain why it only works in Chromium.