# input range thumb animation

Tags: javascript, input, range

I want to transform translateX the scrollbar thumb by some percentage based on an event. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("scrubber").style.transform = "translateX(50px)";
document.getElementById("scrubber").style.transition = "all 0.5s ease-out";
```

I saw this 3 year old related (question)[[Animation is not applied to ::-webkit-slider-thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059860/animation-is-not-applied-to-webkit-slider-thumb?rq=1]). Is it still not possible to animate the thumb? Is there a workaround or hack?

Comment: Did you see the test link in that post?  Not sure, but it might help : https://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element-animation

Comment: I did - and it did not work for me. I still went ahead and asked, just in case there were newer additions I dint yet come across :)